# meta-functions that accepts two List structures

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have started with c++ templates and I think  have managed to understand and for example make the following template

```
struct Nil {
enum { head = ERROR };
typedef Nil Next; };


template<int value_ , class Next_ = Nil>
struct Cons {
enum { head = value_};
typedef Next_ Next;
}
```

But now when I have to write a meta-functions using the templated struct definitions above that accepts two List structures and appends them I even don't know how to start.

for example from `Cons<7,Cons<3,Nil>` and `Cons<1,Cons<9,Nil>>`

to receive

```
Cons<7,Cons<3,Cons<1,Cons<9,Nil>>>>.
```

I will be so happy for any help, materials where to start with meta programming and some code to start wih this task. At least one example to start.

Comment: What is the problems you're having with the shown code? Do you get build errors? Then please copy-paste them *in full and complete* into the question itself (even if they're long and seem to not make much sense).

Comment: You need to think recursively. You can find an algorithm for appending two lists in just about any introduction to functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to join `Cons<value>` and `Next`: the result is `Cons<value, Next>`. To join `Cons<value, Next>` and `Next2` you proceed recursively by first joining `Next` and `Next2`:

```
struct Nil { };

template<int value, class Next = Nil>
struct Cons { };

template<class, class Next>
struct Join {
    using Type = Next;
};

template<int value, class Next, class Next2>
struct Join<Cons<value, Next>, Next2> {
    using Type = Cons<value, typename Join<Next, Next2>::Type>;
};

template<int value, class Next>
struct Join<Cons<value>, Next> {
    using Type = Cons<value, Next>;
};
```

Simple tests:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    Join<
        Nil,
        Cons<4, Cons<5, Cons<6>>>>::Type,
    Cons<4, Cons<5, Cons<6>>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    Join<
        Cons<1, Cons<2, Cons<3>>>,
        Nil>::Type,
    Cons<1, Cons<2, Cons<3>>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    Join<
        Cons<1, Cons<2, Cons<3>>>,
        Cons<4, Cons<5, Cons<6>>>>::Type,
    Cons<1, Cons<2, Cons<3, Cons<4, Cons<5, Cons<6>>>>>>>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PcpPkt)